# scala json4s in for comprehension - cannot resolve symbol flatMap

Tags: scala, json4s, for-comprehension

I would like to use functions in for-comprehension with input/return values of type JValue, that is defined within json4s. The following snippet:

```scala
def func1(...):org.json4s.JValue
def func2(val1:org.json4s.JValue):...

for {
  aJValue <- func1(...) 
  whatever <- func2(aJValue) 
} yield (wathever)
```

yields the compiler error

> Cannot resolve symbol flatMap

at the first "<-" symbol. How to fix this?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Why using a `for` comprehension at all? just use normal variables.

Comment: for comprehensions just ease using nested flatMap and map (and withFilter) methods. flatMap signature is something like (for container type C[_]) `def flatMap[B](f: A => C[B]): C[B]`. if you want to insist on using for, func2 also must return JValue. but I agree to the above comment, just use func2(func1(...)).

Comment: Uh, you are completely right :) Thanks! I leave the question, as it is, maybe it helps someone somewhere...

Comment: BEWARE: [json4s is vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks!](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)